# Do repeated imports into views affect performance in a Django application?

Tags: python, django, python-import

In a situation like this:

```py
# views.py
def myView(request):
    import something
    import other
    
    something.doStuff()
    other.doOtherStuff()
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)

def myOtherView(request):
    import something
    import other
    
    something.doThings()
    other.doOtherThings()
    return render(request, 'page2.html', context)
```

Is importing stuff at view-level a bad practice? Does it affect performance?

```py
# views.py
import something
import other

def myView(request):
    something.doStuff()
    other.doOtherStuff()
    return render(request, 'page.html', context)

def myOtherView(request):
    something.doThings()
    other.doOtherThings()
    return render(request, 'page2.html', context)
```

Is this second version better/faster?

Comment: The main reason why the first is better is because it can pro-actively detect imports to missing modules.

Answer (score 1):

> Does it affect performance?

It will make not much difference. An `import` statement will look if it has already loaded the module, and add the module into scope. Given the module thus has been loaded already (for example at startup, or when you triggered a view that loaded the module), it will only make it a fraction of a millisecond slower, since it simply realizes it has loaded the module, and then moves the items into scope.

*Local imports* are sometimes even required, since it would result in an import cycle: where one module *A* imports module *B*, and *B* then triggers importing *A* while *A* is still in the loading process. In that case we can break the cycle by triggering to load module *B* only when a function is triggered, and thus at least first finishing loading module *A* before loading *B*.

But the local imports also have another downside: it makes it easier for bugs to arise: if you import a non-existing module, or later move that module to somewhere else, it is possible the import statement thus aims to load a module that (no longer) exists, but it can be hard to find out where the import breaks: it would require triggering all views, whereas loading the items at the top of the file will proactively load the modules, and thus raise an error. This makes it easier to spot bugs.

Comment: Yas, I usually do import inside functions on the models.py file, because it often happens that you import models from there and you can easily run into a circular import error. But for other files, I  need reasons to enforce my colleagues to put imports at the top of the file for order and readability. 
Would that be still true if the imports are inside function called very often? And there are HUNDREDS of the same one in the same file?